# PyCharm remote docker-compose interpreter Unknown command: 'python'

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging

I try to debug an existing Django project in Pycharm on Linux, using an existing docker-compose file and a remote interpreter.

I followed a tutorial on configuring the docker-compose interpreter and the run configuration and the configurations look like this:
[image]
[image]

When I try to start the project, the right docker container is launcher, but I get the error:

```
Attaching to docker_web_1
web_1                    | Unknown command: 'python'
web_1                    | Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.
_web_1 exited with code 1
```

I have tried other interpreter paths (e.g. /usr/bin/python2.7) but the error remains. Did I miss something in this configuration?

I've tried adding the following snippet to my dockerfile, but it did not help:

```
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Does it work correctly outside of PyCharm?

Comment: Try adding `./manage.py` or similiar to the custom run command field.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the same error

Comment: No I'm sorry. I just start docker-compose in a separate bash terminal

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked a long time ago but there it goes for the people who come later...

I paste the image, if further explanations are required, ask for them.

( I use runserver_plus but it works for runserver either )

[image]